# Eiffel: regular expressions how to do grouping

Tags: eiffel

I'd like to do grouping of regular expressions with eiffel. How do I do something like

```
l_reg.compile ("^([0-9]{3}) (rabbit[0-9]).*")
l_groups := l_reg.groups ("123 rabbit1")
my_first_rabbit := l_groups.at (2)
```

Didn't find any example on groups, `LX_DFA_REGULAR_EXPRESSION` class and other googlings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use `RX_PCRE_REGULAR_EXPRESSION` instead of `LX_DFA_REGULAR_EXPRESSION`:

Including `$ISE_LIBRARY\contrib\library\gobo\library\regexp\src\library.ecf` library

```
l_reg: RX_PCRE_REGULAR_EXPRESSION
...
l_reg.compile ("^([0-9]{3}) (rabbit[0-9]).*")
l_reg.match ("123 rabbit1")
my_first_rabbit := l_reg.captured_substring (2)
```

There is no `groups` routine, although it could be implemented by calling `captured_substring` internally. There is only a routine `split` which does the reverse: returns the substrings which did not match the regular expression.

Something like

```
    regex_groups (a_haystack, a_needle: STRING): ARRAY[STRING]
            -- Test with https://www.regextester.com/1911
        require
            regex_match (a_haystack, a_needle)
        local
            l_reg: RX_PCRE_REGULAR_EXPRESSION
            l_index: like {RX_PCRE_REGULAR_EXPRESSION}.match_count
        do
            create Result.make_empty
            create l_reg.make
            l_reg.compile (a_needle)
            if l_reg.is_compiled then
                l_reg.match (a_haystack)
                from
                    l_index := 1
                until
                    l_index > l_reg.match_count
                loop
                    Result.extend (l_reg.captured_substring (l_index))
                    l_index := l_index + 1
                end
            else
                --- error compiling regex
                fallible.set_last_error (create {SIT_INTERNAL_ERROR}.make ("regex_group-> regex does not compile:" + a_needle))
            end
        ensure
            not fallible.has_error
            instance_free: Class
        end
```

you could test your regex here: https://www.regextester.com/1911

Comment: which regexp standard is following this library? Thx

Comment: A subset of PCRE: https://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcresyntax.html